# PHP OOP classes and autoloader

Tags: php

I have the autoloader php code is this:

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php"); // comma-separated list
spl_autoload_register(
function ($pClassName) {
spl_autoload(strtolower(str_replace("\\", "/", $pClassName)));
});
```

So, in my index is the following:

```
<?php 
namespace index;
use request\request;
```

The class request is in the following folder:

```
vendor/request/request.php
```

And the namespace of that class is:

```
namespace request;
class request {
// protected functions here 
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'request\request' not found
```

Also tried with use index\request and index\request\request. The error is the same!

What is the problem ? also charset tried to set ANSI and UTF-8 the problem isn't come from charset encoding.

Comment: Where is the "autoloader php" code placed?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's because your non-vendor code (index and autoloader) lies outside of the `vendor` directory on your filesystem. If your `index.php` is always going to be the entry point, then this is a pretty simple fix: Make sure the `spl_autoload` function is aware of the `vendor` directory:

```
spl_autoload(getcwd() .'/vendor/'.strtolower(str_replace("\\", "/", $pClassName)));
```

You could also use `__DIR__` instead of `getcwd()` to do this, and that'll technically be faster. I didn't do it because I'm not sure where on the filesystem this autoload code is.